Why does Go not throw an error when dereferencing a dangling pointer immediately after a variable goes out of scope?
I’m learning about Go’s memory management and garbage collection, and I’ve encountered some unexpected behavior when trying to dereference a pointer after the variable it points to goes out of scope.
In Go, I understand that garbage collection (GC) is automatic and that pointers can sometimes reference memory that is no longer valid. I expected that dereferencing a pointer to an out-of-scope variable would throw an error, but it seems like Go doesn't throw an error when doing so
Here’s a minimal example that demonstrates the issue:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    var p *int
    {
        x := 42
        p = &x  // p points to x
        fmt.Println(*p) // Prints 42
    }

    // Force garbage collection (for testing)
    runtime.GC()

    // Dereferencing p here should cause an error (since x is out of scope)
    fmt.Println(*p) // This does NOT throw any error
}

What I expected:

I expected that after the inner block where x goes out of scope, the pointer p would be a "dangling pointer" and would immediately cause a runtime error when dereferenced.
The error I expected is something like: runtime: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference.

What actually happens:

The program does not panic or throw an error when dereferencing *p even after forcing garbage collection. The value printed is still the address of x even though x is out of scope.


The scope of a variable identifier is the extent of source text in which the identifier denotes the variable.  Scope is unrelated to lifetime of the variable.

Your expectations seem to be based on how C works and not what the language specification of Go requires for Go. It is always helpful to stop guessing and stop trying to transfer knowledge but consult the official (short and readable) specification first.

The GC does not care about the scope. It checks if there are active pointers to a memory object. In your case, there is at least one.
The variable x may be out of scope, but p is not, and it is pointing to x, and there is a goroutine using p, so x will not be garbage collected. It will be ready for collection after the function returns, because p will be out of scope as well.
